# efficient way to replace vector of values according to second vector of bin values in R

Tags: r

I have a vector of numeric values (`vals.to.convert` in example code below) representing elevations (in meters). I need to replace each value with a related metric that are associated with 1-meter bins (data in the 'becomes' column of the `conversion.df` data.frame below).

Right now I'm using `cut()` with `conversion.df$becomes` as the labels then coercing with `as.character()` and `as.numeric()` to get the binned numeric conversion.

Can anyone recommend a more efficient and elegant way to do this?

For example, with a raster, you can use `raster::reclassify` and a data.frame structured like `conversion.df` to make the substitution.

Here is example code:

```
vals.to.convert <- sample(1:80, 500, replace = T)

conversion.df <- data.frame(from = 0:79,
                 to = 1:80,
                 becomes = runif(80))

converted <- as.numeric(as.character(cut(vals.to.convert, 0:nrow(conversion.df), labels = conversion.df$becomes)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use findInterval

```
converted <- conversion.df$becomes[
                findInterval(vals.to.convert, conversion.df$from) - 1L]
```

or cut

```
converted <- conversion.df$becomes [cut(vals.to.convert, 0:80)]
```